# What is best way to fetch data from two table with one to many relationship?

Tags: sql

Here is table structure:

**Table Task**

```
id(PK) name
1      Task 1
2      Task 2
```

**Table User**

```
id(PK) name  
1     John Smith
2     Jack Will
```

**Table Tasker**

```
id(PK) taskId userId
1         1       1
2       1       2
3       2       1
```

Table task and user have one to many relationship by using Table tasker

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I want result like task detail and all users as tasker can you give me example? @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  T1.taskId,T1.userId,
  T2.name as User_name,
  T3.name as Task_name
from Tasker T1
left join User T2 on T1.userId = T2.ID
left join Task T3 on T1.taskId = T3.ID
```

[image]

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1a7fc/2/0)